# having trouble outputting what i wrote to a file

Tags: c++, file-io

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
ofstream fout1;
ofstream fout2;

string fnameOdd;
string fnameEven;
int x;
int numEven(0);
int numOdd(0);

cout << "Enter name of file for odd integers: ";
getline(cin, fnameOdd);

fout1.open(fnameOdd.c_str(), ios::out);

cout << "Enter name of file for even integers: ";
    getline(cin, fnameEven);

fout2.open(fnameEven.c_str(), ios::out);

if(!fout1.is_open())
{
    cerr << "Unable to open file" << fnameOdd << endl;
    exit(10);
}

if(!fout2.is_open())
{
    cerr << "Unable to open file" << fnameEven << endl;
    exit(15);
}

cout << "Enter list of odd and even integers (followed by 0): " << endl;
cin >> x;
while (x != 0)
{

if (x % 2 == 0)
{
    numEven++;
}
else
{
    numOdd++;
}
}
fout1 << numEven;
fout2 << numOdd;

cout << "File " << fnameOdd << " contains " << numOdd << " odd integers. " <<endl;
cout << "File " << fnameEven << " contains " << numEven << " even integers. " <<endl;


fout1.close();
fout2.close();

return 0;
}
```

I am having trouble outputting anything to the screen, nothing is happening it is just inputting the file names and integers. i am not sure how to output what i have wrote onto the file, and reading my book does not help.

Comment: Get rid of all the code except for writing to a file and see if you can get that working.

Answer (score 2):

You forget that your input statement `cin >> x;` needs to go inside the loop as well

```
cin >> x;
while (x != 0)
{
    if (x % 2 == 0)
    {
        numEven++;
    }
    else
    {
        numOdd++;
    }
    cin >> x; // new line here
}
```

The way you wrote it after you input the first value for x, it never changes it's value again. So the while loop never ends. That's why you didn't see any output.